# MVC 3: How do I dynamically enable/disable client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a check out view that serves as a wizard. Steps (5 of them) are contained in their own div's and are shown/hidden via jQuery as a user goes through the checkout process wizard.

On one of the steps, I have payment information. Payment options are "Pay With My Account" or "Pay with my credit card".

Choosing one or the other shows input controls for the chosen payment option. All this works beautifully.

Lets say I choose "Pay with my account" which then hides the credit card inputs and shows the account info inputs. This is again done through jQuery by hiding the containing div.

When I go to hit the next button, client side validation fires on the hidden credit card inputs (the containing div is hidden).

My question is, how can I use javascript/jQuery to dynamically enable/disable the validation on the hidden input controls?

Thanks in advance for any replies...

Comment: You can manually add and remove the rules that are placed on the input files. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules

Comment: I ended up stumbling upon MVC Foolproof Validation over at CodePlex (http://http://foolproof.codeplex.com/). Does everything I need to and more and I didn't have to reinvent the wheel. :)

Comment: @Ed DeGagne you can answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer if you want. At the bottom of the page is something that says "Answer your question" I think it's a best practice kinda thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up stumbling upon MVC Foolproof Validation over at CodePlex (http://foolproof.codeplex.com).

It does everything I need to and more and I didn't have to reinvent the wheel. :)